# “has the same colour” vs “is the same colour”

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Am I right both sentences are correct and usable?

> Andy’s car **has** the same colour as Laura’s car.
>
> Andy’s car **is** the same colour as Laura’s car.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] *Andy’s car has the same colour as Laura’s car*.
>
> [2] *Andy’s car is the same colour as Laura’s car.*

[1] is not at all natural. We don't normally use the verb "have" to describe the colour of a car.

[2] is fine, though you can drop "car" from the comparative clause. Note that comparative clauses are normally obligatorily reduced in some way relative to the structure of main clauses.

We understand: Andy's car is *x* colour; Laura's car is *y* colour; *x=y*

Comment: So, the best choise is "Andy’s car is the same colour as Laura’s.", isn't it?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, you are right. "Car" can be omitted".

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is correct & formal.
But your second sentence is absolutely ok.

In your second sentence, you could also use a PP, *'of the same colour'* instead of *'the same colour'* :

> *"Andy’s car is **of** the same colour as Laura’s car."*

You could omit the noun 'car' after 'Laura's' :

> *"Andy’s car is **of** the same colour as Laura’s."*

(Laura's = Laura's car).

Comment: My examples are from very famous book and there is mistake existence is about some minimum. Are you sure about your correction?

Comment: Both *"Andy’s car is of the same colour as Laura’s"* and *""Andy’s car is the same colour as Laura’s"* are correct.